# Databinding combobox column to object (or null) in DGV

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, nhibernate, data-binding

I've done something similar to this in the past and it worked well (except one slightly dirty hack).

I have an object, Machine, that references other objects, like Building, Level, etc. I'm databinding this in a DGV. I have the object lookup columns set up as a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`. I had to do the "Self" property hack as mentioned in a few other posts in order to get the ComboBox to return the object itself instead of an ID or something.

```
BuildingColumn.DataSource = buildings ' Loaded in from DB
BuildingColumn.DataPropertyName = "Building" ' Machine.Building
BuildingColumn.DisplayMember = "Abbreviation" ' Abbreviation of building
BuildingColumn.ValueMember = "Self" ' A property on the Building object that returns itself
```

I'd like to get rid of the "Self" if possible, but that's really a secondary issue.

The primary problem is that I get DGV Data Errors on the rows where the Machine.Building = Nothing. How do I avoid this? It might also be related that I would like to add an empty option into the ComboBox so the user can empty out the building if they need to. I thought that adding an empty value to the datasource of the ComboBox would fix both of these issues, but it did not.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this question was related to my other issue: [DataGridViewComboBoxCell Empty Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20593475/datagridviewcomboboxcell-empty-value)

The issue here was due to the O/RM that I'm using: NHibernate. Some of the child properties of the objects I retrieved were proxy objects, so when I tried to bind them to a comboBox where the objects were non-proxy objects there was a type mismatch.

The two main solutions for this issue are to use eager fetching, or to create a view for the objects being bound to ensure that a non-proxy object is always available.