# DataGridViewComboBoxCell Empty Value

Tags: .net, vb.net, nhibernate, data-binding

I have a DGV with a few combo box columns. These columns are bound to objects that are basically lookup items in a database. I'd like to provide a blank option for my users to set these lookup items to NULL where it's applicable. I've tried various methods of adding a Null item to the list to allow the user to select the empty value, but it does not seem to work.

Is there a best method to do this that will allow me to bind my list to the control, and also allow the user to enter a null value without having to press Ctrl+0?

```
Public Class RootItem
    Public Overridable Property Lookup
    Public Overridable Property Type as String
    Public Overridable Property Active as Boolean
End Class

Public Class LookupItem
    Public Overridable Property ID As Integer = -1
    Public Overridable Property Abbreviation As String = ""
    Public Overridable Property Name As String = ""
    Public Overridable Property Description As String = ""

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return Abbreviation
    End Function

    Public Overridable ReadOnly Property Self
        Get
            Return Me
        End Get
    End Property
End Class

' My databinding
' ...
private rootItems as IList(of RootItem) = session.QueryOver(of RootItem).List

Private lookups As IList(Of LookupItem) = session.QueryOver(Of LookupItem).List

With LookupItemColumn
    .DataSource = lookupItems
    .DataPropertyName = PropUtil.GetName(Of RootItem)(Function(x) x.LookupItem)
    .DisplayMember = PropUtil.GetName(Of LookupItem)(Function(x) x.Abbreviation)
    .ValueMember = PropUtil.GetName(Of LookupItem)(Function(x) x.Self)
End With

myDgv.DataSource = New SortableBindingList(Of RootItem)(rootItems)
```

Comment: So adding a "null item" to the dropdown source is not an option?

Comment: I have done this, but then the binding does not work properly and none of the items display in the drop down.

Comment: Since your model doesn't allow null, the only way i can think of that might work, is to create a custom `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`.

Comment: How does my model disallow null? Since the property I'm binding to is a Nullable Object (a class), shouldn't it be allowed?

Comment: I was assuming you were using datatables. Maybe you could provide some code? :)

Comment: Okey, so I did some testing. I can successfully display a null value of `LookupItem` in the grid. But when the edit control try to populate the items it throws an ArgumentNullException, and that is why I think you should create your own custom column. The ComboBox.ObjectCollection doesn't allow null values. Or you can populate the ComboBox manually through the EditingControlShowing event of the grid.

Comment: Come to think of it, by changing the `LookupItem` to a structure (if possible) might do the trick. I did bind a list of structures to a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn a while a go. I also added a shared parse method to the object, which I by accident discovered the datagridview search for when trying to parse an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution to this problem was to have all of the items that I was binding to ComboBoxes implement a LookupItem interface.

With this, I took each of the lists of items that I wanted to bind to and added a "dummy" item.

Then, I handled the `CellValueChanged` event and used some reflection to detect if the column being edited was a ComboBoxColumn, and if so - it would get the property that the column was bound to, and find out if the value it was now set to was my Dummy item (I determined this by using an empty ID). If it is the empty item, it sets the value of that property (using reflection again) to Null. This way, users can easily set properties to null, and my objects are still persisted to the database properly. It's also not too difficult to add more columns because it just has to implement the LookupItem interface.